# What are the brown spots on my apples?

Tags: diagnosis, pest-control, diseases, apples, bugs

For a while now my apple tree's fruit has been growing with brown spots all over them. The more they grow, the worse they look. I'm wondering if this is a pest problem. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Hey Tom.  Really need some pictures and some more information. We can definitely help..

Comment: Sounds like apple scab but need picture to confirm,

Comment: Welcome Tom! In addition to pictures, here are some important questions. Where do you live? How old is the tree? Are the leaves and the rest of the tree healthy? Can you be more specific about how long this has been happening?  Has it ever happened before, or is this episode the first time? Just press [edit] and you can add everything. Our site is different from some others, so I invite you to visit our [help]. [Ask] is a good place to start. If you need help with features of the site, just let us know! Have fun!